# Gamedev: how should I manage the AI using lua scripts?

Tags: c++, scripting, lua, game-ai

My game is in C++ and I want to make AI being managed by lua scripts, but I have no idea how should the scripts look like and the integration in C++.

Should the script be like

```
   if (whatever_happening) do_something
   if (....) .....
   etc
```

And in every frame in C++ I should call for every enemy:

```
   foreach(enemy)
   enemy.handleAi(luascript.file)
```

Or it is wrong and I should handle it different?

Answer (score 2):

To answer your other question about how the AI scripts should look like, that's more appropriate for [gamedev.stackexchange](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ai). Have a look at this question and the answers: https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/2194/new-to-creating-ai-where-to-start

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [LuaBind](http://www.rasterbar.com/products/luabind.html).

> Luabind is a library that helps you create bindings between C++ and Lua. It has the ability to expose functions and classes, written in C++, to Lua. It will also supply the functionality to define classes in lua and let them derive from other lua classes or C++ classes. Lua classes can override virtual functions from their C++ baseclasses.